# JSR-303 validated property does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding

Tags: hibernate, validation, bean-validation

0.4 and hibernate validator 4.1.0.Final, I created a custom validator for validating password and confirmPassword fields, but the validator thrown the following exception:

```
00:16:11,891 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator] (http--192.168.1.20-8080-6) ValidationMessages not found.
00:16:11,892 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator] (http--192.168.1.20-8080-6) org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages found
00:16:11,894 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver] (http--192.168.1.20-8080-6) Resolving exception from handler [deliveries.manager.controller.AdminSignUpController@455901d2]: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String deliveries.manager.controller.AdminSignUpController.submitProduct(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model,deliveries.manager.pagebean.AdminSignupBean,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'password.confirmPassword' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
00:16:11,897 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver] (http--192.168.1.20-8080-6) Resolving exception from handler [deliveries.manager.controller.AdminSignUpController@455901d2]: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String deliveries.manager.controller.AdminSignUpController.submitProduct(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model,deliveries.manager.pagebean.AdminSignupBean,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'password.confirmPassword' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
00:16:11,900 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (http--192.168.1.20-8080-6) Resolving exception from handler [deliveries.manager.controller.AdminSignUpController@455901d2]: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String deliveries.manager.controller.AdminSignUpController.submitProduct(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model,deliveries.manager.pagebean.AdminSignupBean,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'password.confirmPassword' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
00:16:11,902 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--192.168.1.20-8080-6) Could not complete request: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String deliveries.manager.controller.AdminSignUpController.submitProduct(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model,deliveries.manager.pagebean.AdminSignupBean,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'password.confirmPassword' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:181) [spring-web-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:427) [spring-webmvc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
```

Here is the bean class:

```
@CompareStrings(propertyNames={"password", "confirmPassword"}, message="Password and Comfirm Password must be matched.")
public class AdminSignupBean {
   private String password = "";
        private String confirmPassword = "";
   private String emailAddress = "";
        private String firstName = "";
        private String lastName = "";
        private String gender = "M";
        private String loginName = "";
        private String address1 = "";
        private String address2 = "";
        private String suburb = "";
        private String state = "";
        private String postcode = "";
        private String phone = "";
...
<settings and getters>
```

Validator class:

```
public class CompareStringsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CompareStrings, Object> {

    public enum StringComparisonMode {
        EQUAL, EQUAL_IGNORE_CASE, NOT_EQUAL, NOT_EQUAL_IGNORE_CASE
    }

    private String[] propertyNames;
    private StringComparisonMode comparisonMode;
    private boolean allowNull;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CompareStrings constraintAnnotation) {
        this.propertyNames = constraintAnnotation.propertyNames();
        this.comparisonMode = constraintAnnotation.matchMode();
        this.allowNull = constraintAnnotation.allowNull();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object target, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean isValid = true;
        List<String> propertyValues = new ArrayList<String> (propertyNames.length);
        for(int i=0; i<propertyNames.length; i++) {
            String propertyValue = ConstraintValidatorHelper.getPropertyValue(String.class, propertyNames[i], target);
            if(propertyValue == null) {
                if(!allowNull) {
                    isValid = false;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                propertyValues.add(propertyValue);
            }
        }

        if(isValid) {
            isValid = ConstraintValidatorHelper.isValid(propertyValues, comparisonMode);
        }

        if (!isValid) {
          /*
           * if custom message was provided, don't touch it, otherwise build the
           * default message
           */
          String message = context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate();
          message = (message.isEmpty()) ?  ConstraintValidatorHelper.resolveMessage(propertyNames, comparisonMode) : message;

          context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
          ConstraintViolationBuilder violationBuilder = context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message);
          for (String propertyName : propertyNames) {
            NodeBuilderDefinedContext nbdc = violationBuilder.addNode(propertyName);
            nbdc.addConstraintViolation();
          }
        }    

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
public String submitProduct(HttpServletRequest req, Model model, 
          @ModelAttribute("adminsignup") @Valid final AdminSignupBean adminsignup,
                         BindingResult result, ModelMap map)
   {   
      UUID pbid=adminsignup.getPbid();
                logger.debug("====adminsignup:"+adminsignup.toString());

                if (result.hasErrors()) {
                    AdminSignupBean admin = products.get(pbid);
                    req.getSession().setAttribute("pbid", pbid);
                    BeanUtils.copyProperties(adminsignup, admin, new String[] {"pbid", "mpf", "password", "confirmPassword"});
                    map.addAttribute("adminsignupbean",admin);

                    return "adminsignup/createadmin";
                }
                Set<ConstraintViolation<AdminSignupBean>> violations 
                        = validatorFactory.getValidator().validate(adminsignup);
                for(ConstraintViolation<AdminSignupBean> violation : violations) {
                    logger.debug("=========Violation Message:- " + violation.getMessage());
                }
                if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
                    logger.debug("=====violations messages:"+violations.toString());
                    AdminSignupBean admin = products.get(pbid);
                    req.getSession().setAttribute("pbid", pbid);
                    BeanUtils.copyProperties(adminsignup, admin, new String[] {"pbid", "mpf", "password", "confirmPassword"});
                    map.addAttribute("adminsignupbean",admin);

                    return "adminsignup/createadmin";
                }
```

Any suggestion is very appreciated.
Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 3):

This seems to me a problem of the [SpringValidatorAdapter](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/SpringValidatorAdapter.java#L147). It seems that this adapter post processes the constraint violations and expects that the violations match existing entity properties. This is not a requirement from the Bean Validation side. I can see that in your custom constraint validator in some cases you are building a custom error. Is this the case when the exception occurs?

I am not a Spring expert, but I think there are multiple ways to integrate Bean Validation in Spring, especially if you only need JSR 303. Have you for example looked at the [LocalValidatorFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I also just ran into this issue. This is indeed because of Spring's implementation, more exactly how Spring access properties: through getters. If there is a validation error on a property, Spring bean's logic will access the property through it's getter. In this case the getter `getConfirmPassword()` is missing (or wrongly spelled). Each property needs a corresponding getter for validation in Spring.

I also think this is bad implementation of Spring. One use case that is not possible because of it:

```
//The validator will make sure that each String in the list is a valid enum value
@EnumValidator(enumClass = SomeEnum.class) 
private final List<String> someEnumList;

//Since the validation guarantees that each String is a valid enum, the conversion can happen here
public List<SomeEnum> getSomeEnumList() {
    return someEnumList.stream().map(SomeEnum::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The above code will throw a 500 instead of a 422 if an incorrect value is passed because of Spring's implementation: after the validation, which correctly sees the problem, Spring will access the getter and an `InvocationException` will be thrown